What is the provenance of Genesis 50:33 in the Joseph Smith Translation?
The Joseph Smith Translation of Genesis contains a curious verse which does not appear to be attested in the Masoretic Text. It's apparently often used as a proof-text for the Mormon religion:

And that seer will I bless, and they that seek to destroy him shall be confounded; for this promise I give unto you; for I will remember you from generation to generation; and his name shall be called Joseph, and it shall be after the name of his father; and he shall be like unto you; for the thing which the Lord shall bring forth by his hand shall bring my people unto salvation (Genesis 50:33 Joseph Smith Translation)

Where does this text originate from? What sources is this drawing from? Are there any ancient textual witnesses for this verse?

Short Answer: There is no biblical manuscript support for Joseph Smith’s additions to Genesis.
According to churchofjesuschrist.org:

Joseph Smith Translation (JST) A revision or translation of the King
James Version of the Bible begun by the Prophet Joseph Smith in June
1830. He was divinely commissioned to make the translation and regarded it as “a branch of his calling” as a prophet.

Also note, that from the introduction it states:

The Lord inspired the Prophet Joseph Smith to restore truths to the
King James Bible text that had become lost or changed since the
original words were written. These restored truths clarified doctrine
and improved scriptural understanding.

The conclusion then is this: Genesis 50:33 in the JST originates from Joseph Smith’s own translation and revision of the Bible, and it does not have ancient textual witnesses outside of the JST itself.

According to the OP's own citation reference (from Wikipedia), Gen 50:33 is one, according to Philip Barlow, who observes the six basic types of changes, one of which is

Long additions that have little or no biblical parallel, such as the
visions of Moses and Enoch, and the passage on Melchizedek

There is no ancient textual basis for these additions, nor many of the other emendations made by Joseph Smith.  He claimed to be a prophet of God who had given him divine inspiration and the authority to make such radical changes.  That is why the Church of LDS call this the "Inspired version".
